# How to Convert double to int in C?

Tags: c

```
double a;
a = 3669.0;
int b;
b = a;
```

I am getting 3668 in b, instead of 3669.

How do I fix This problem?
 And if have 3559.8 like that also I want like 3559 not 3560.

Comment: That's interesting. `3669.0` is exactly representable in floating-point...

Comment: @Mysticial: Hmm yes, that number should have been stored as 3669 in floating point format. Perhaps, an issue with the compiler.

Comment: Should 3668.51 map to 3669 too? (Are you trying to round, or just clip numbers that are really close?)

Comment: The code is a lie. The OP has a complicated calculation that he thinks is resulting in `3669.0` but it's really resulting in slightly less.

Comment: I ran this and got 3669 in b. Here is the result [link]http://www.ideone.com/yWT5G

Comment: @Gabe: Yup, that's exactly my conclusion - see my answer.

Comment: @ratty: Have you tried compiling and running the exact code in your example?  I have, and it works correctly.  Put something closer to your real code up.

Comment: A good answer [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526070).

Answer (score 71):

I suspect you don't *actually* have that problem - I suspect you've really got:

```
double a = callSomeFunction();
// Examine a in the debugger or via logging, and decide it's 3669.0

// Now cast
int b = (int) a;
// Now a is 3668
```

What makes me say that is that although it's true that many decimal values *cannot* be stored exactly in `float` or `double`, that doesn't hold for integers of this kind of magnitude. They can very easily be exactly represented in binary floating point form. (Very large integers can't always be exactly represented, but we're not dealing with a very large integer here.)

I strongly suspect that your `double` value is *actually* slightly less than 3669.0, but it's being displayed to you as 3669.0 by whatever diagnostic device you're using. The conversion to an integer value just performs truncation, not rounding - hence the issue.

Assuming your `double` type is an IEEE-754 64-bit type, the largest value which is less than 3669.0 is exactly

```
3668.99999999999954525264911353588104248046875
```

So if you're using any diagnostic approach where that value would be shown as 3669.0, then it's quite possible (probable, I'd say) that this is what's happening.

Comment: Try adding something like `printf("a = %.50f\n", a);` to see the actual value of `a`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Personally I use a bit of code I've got in C# which handles the binary value directly :)

Comment: This is the answer. And an excellent answer at that! My question: What happens when @Jon Skeet's score gets too big for SO? Will our appreciation for Jon Skeet eventually kill SO?

Answer (score 7):

```
main() {
    double a;
    a=3669.0;
    int b;
    b=a;
    printf("b is %d",b);
  
}
```

output is :`b is 3669`

when you write b=a; then its automatically converted in int

```
see on-line compiler result :
```

http://ideone.com/60T5b

---

This is called **Implicit Type Conversion**
Read more here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implicit-type-conversion-in-c-with-examples/

Comment: "_converted in double_" in `int`?

Comment: oh ya in int...sory its my mistakes

Answer (score 3):

This is the notorious floating point rounding issue. Just add a very small number, to correct the issue.

```
double a;
a=3669.0;
int b;
b=a+ 1e-9;
```

Comment: There should be no problem here at all, as 3669.0 is exactly representable in binary floating point.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes I agree. For this particular number, the issue shouldn't occur. I guess something wrong with the compiler maybe or OP hasn't given exact case that's causing the issue.

Comment: The latter is *much* more likely to be the case, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> How to Convert double to int in C?

Quick answer. (Does not meet OP's implied goal need of rounding.):

```
// Discard the fractional part of d - truncation.
// Well defined when the truncated d is near the int range.
int i = (int) d;
```

---

Conversions from `double` to `int` should address some issues.

- What to do when the the `double` value's fractional portion is near 1.0, as in OP's true case?  Often a rounded value is preferred.
- How to detect/handle an `double` well out of the `int` range?
- What about infinity and non-a-number?

If range detection not important, round and convert in one step with `long lround(double)`: "... round their argument to the nearest integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction".

```
#include <math.h>
int = (int) lround(d); // Since C99.
```

If range detection is important, 1st use `double` math to detect range.  Take care to get the edge case test correct as conversion to `int` valid from `[INT_MIN - 0.9999... to INT_MAX + 0.9999...]`.  Be sure the math/values used are *exact* as needed.  `(double) INT_MAX` may lose precision when `int` have more value bits than `double` has precision.

```
#include <limits.h>
#define INT_MAX_PLUS1  ((INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)
#define INT_MIN_MINUS1 ((INT_MIN/2 - 1)*2.0)

#if INT_MIN == -INT_MAX
// Rare non-2's complement
if ((d < INT_MAX_PLUS1) && (d > INT_MIN_MINUS1)) {
#else
// 2's complement
if ((d < INT_MAX_PLUS1) && (d + INT_MIN > -1.0)) {
#endif

  i = (int) lround(d);

} else {
  fprintf(stderr, "Value %.17g not near the int range [%d %d]\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
}
```

Commonly `d < INT_MAX_PLUS1` is false when `d` is a [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).  C does not require this behavior, even though *false* is common.  Alternatively:

```
#include <math.h>
if (!isnan(d) && (d < INT_MAX_PLUS1) && (d > INT_MIN_MINUS1)) {
...
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int b;
double a;
a=3669.0;
b=a;
printf("b=%d",b);
```

this code gives the output as b=3669 only you check it clearly.