# What is a safe, cross-platform way to perform range checks before casting to a smaller numeric type?

Tags: c++, casting, c++98, range-checking

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526070/handling-overflow-when-casting-doubles-to-integers-in-c) is the closest duplicate I could find.

Despite the tags, the question seems to be about C, and the usable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424410/2201041) references the C99 spec.

What is the correct way to handle this check in C++98, without using Boost or other libraries?

Comment: Check [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the code from [`gsl::narrow()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util) and tweak it slightly, turning it into `can_narrow()` returning a `bool` rather than `throw`ing:

```
// narrow_cast(): a searchable way to do narrowing casts of values
template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr T narrow_cast(U u) noexcept
{ return static_cast<T>(u); }

namespace details
{
    template<class T, class U>
    struct is_same_signedness : public std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_signed<T>::value == std::is_signed<U>::value>
    {};
}

template<class T, class U>
inline bool can_narrow(U u)
{
    T t = narrow_cast<T>(u);
    if (static_cast<U>(t) != u)
        return false;
    if (!details::is_same_signedness<T, U>::value && ((t < T{}) != (u < U{})))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like can_narrow<int>(2.0001) will return false, no?

Comment: "Range check" is a question whether a _specific value_ can be safely reduced into a target type, rather than whether the source type range exceeds the target type range.  As long as `u` is within `(std::numeric_limits::lowest<T>(), std::numeric_limits::max<T>())`, shouldn't the range check return true?