# Why does converting an large double to a uint16_t with optimizations on gcc and clang give different answers

Tags: c++, gcc

The code below produces a different result on gcc when optimizations are turned on. Without optimizations gcc produces the same result as clang.

```c++
#include <cfloat>
#include <cstdint>

double big_dbl() { return DBL_MAX; }

int main() {
    return static_cast<std::uint16_t>(big_dbl());
}
```

The assembler output for `-O0` shows that both gcc and clang call `empty_dbl` and use `cvttsd2si` to do the floating point->int conversion followed by a conversion to a 16-bit unsigned value and produce `0`. Turning up the optimization level to `-01` optimizes the `empty_dbl` call away in both compilers but clang still gives `0` as the result of the cast whereas gcc gives 65535. The results can be seen with [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yi_p07).

Is this a bug in the gcc optimizer or undefined behaviour so the optimizer can do what it likes?

This has bitten us recently, and in some sense thankfully, as it showed a scenario where `big_dbl` was used incorrectly and we have fixed the code properly but I would like to understand the differences with gcc.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526070/handling-overflow-when-casting-doubles-to-integers-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quote](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv#fpint-1) from the current draft standard:

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

So implementations can do whatever they like for your case, as the behavior is undefined.