# sqrt function in C++ issue

Tags: c++, sqrt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    int i = sqrt(1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)) - 1;
    
    cout << i;
}
```

I have written a simple program which utilizes the `sqrt()` function in C++. The above program prints out a negative value on the console for n = 32768 even though the input to `sqrt()` is positive. I tried changing the statement from `int i = sqrt(1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)) - 1;` to 
`double i  = sqrt(1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)) - 1;` but the error is not resolving.

**Output:**

32768
-2147483648

The above output is for `int i = sqrt(1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)) - 1;`

Please help!

Comment: Try changing `n` to `double`

Comment: `1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)` is an expression of type `int`. It seems to have overflowed.

Comment: If the result of calling `sqrt` (or any other function) doesn’t make sense, look at the argument(s) that it’s being called with.

Comment: Try calculating `1 + 2 * 32768 * (32768 + 1)` by hand you would quickly notice that it is `2147549185` and likely overflowed `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `int n` to `double n`. Your calculation `1 + 2 * n * (n + 1)` overflows the range of `int` which for 32bits is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Side note: `int` may not be 32bit, it depends on the platform (however, usually most of the time it is 32bit)

Comment: That's right, except overflow isn't guaranteed. Attempting to cast a double outside of representable range to int is UB. See SO post [Handling overflow when casting doubles to integers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424410/13223986).